# Delete Where Exists

Tags: sql, sql-delete, exists

```
delete from VA_demo_setup_NCSC_temp 
    where exists
    (select *
     from VA_demo_setup_enrolled va
     where VA_demo_setup_NCSC_temp.student_id = va.student_id
       and VA_demo_setup_NCSC_temp.academic_period = va.academic_period);
```

I’ve seen a couple of similar posts to this but I haven’t been able to decipher why this particular query takes hours.  I am trying to remove the records where id and period are in both datasets.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Add table definitions, incl indexes. Also add some sample table data, and the expected result. (Well formatted text!)

Comment: Have you indexed your search field (id and academic_period)?

Comment: How large are the tables at all, how many records are you going to delete, are these production tables that are used while youre trying to delete records, are child tables affected by cascading deletes, are triggers active?

Comment: Deleting values with lots of indexes; the index records have to be removed as well.  So if this table has LOTS of indexes.  could be slow due to having to update the indexes; and if it's on a table with lots of transactions occurring against it, the necessary locks may take some time to process.

Comment: Could you post an explain plan?

Comment: I'm using a million records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier to explain the poor performance if we had sight of your table structures and indices.  However your query can be re-written as below.  you might find it performs better this way and this is the more standard approach to deleting data in the manner you require.

```
DELETE          vt
FROM            VA_demo_setup_NCSC_temp vt
    INNER JOIN  VA_demo_setup_enrolled va ON vt.student_id = va.student_id AND vt.academic_period = va.academic_period;
```

Perhaps you have a primary key on the VA_demo_setup_NCSC_temp table that consists of a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?  (In which case the re-written query wouldn't change the performance)

Comment: Maybe - not all RDBMSs support writing the query this way.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yeah, I have assumed SQL Server here whilst waiting for more information.  Out of interest - which database management systems don't allow this syntax?

Comment: delete *
 from VA_demo_setup_NCSC_temp e
 where mergedId in (select mergedId from VA_demo_setup_enrolled);

Comment: I used the solution posted above.  I am using SAS proc SQL.